# Align center when element width < viewport, align right + scroll when element width > viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment, viewport

I'd like to have an element centered inside a viewport as long as it is smaller than the viewport and scrollable + aligned right as long as it is bigger than the viewport. Like this:

[image]

[image]

First I tried without Javascript, but float and overflow are knocking each other out. Then I tried putting a div with float:right next to the element and setting it's width programatically through Javascript. But the element wouldn't stick to the right when it's smaller than the viewport.

I'm out of ideas now, any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: Is the element size dynamic?

Comment: can you use jQuery?

Comment: @Frits: yes, it's a category breadcrumb (once loaded inside the page it won't change anymore during that page call),
shall: yes

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, which works if it's possible for you to replace the regular spaces inside the text with non-breaking-space entities `&nbsp;`:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKgydN

Here is the essential part of the settings:

```
.x1 { /* wrapper for text container */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.x2 { /* text container */
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

So it's a reverse flex container with only one flex item which is not allowed to grow or shrink, has `margin: 0 auto` for centering and `align-items: flex-start` for right alignment when it's becoming narrower than the parent element/viewport.

EDIT/additional remark: I forgot about the scrolling ability, and right now I can't find a solution for it. Nevertheless, I leave this "half answer" here - maybe someone else comes up with the rest....

Comment: Nice idea using flex. Unfortunately, in the end it behaves exactly like float (no overflow possible). But thanks for the idea! :)

Comment: overflow *is* possible (see codepen), but scrolling unfortunately isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I have achieved the desired behaviour by utilizing JQuery. It's not perfect and I still wish there would be a solution without Javascript.

Here's what I've done to make it work.

HTML:

```
<div class="breadcrumb-scroller-container">
    <div class="breadcrumb-scroller">
      scroller content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.breadcrumb-scroller-container {
    text-align: center;
}

.breadcrumb-scroller {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Javascript (JQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // scroll left to a maximum of 10000px just to be sure
    $(".breadcrumb-scroller").scrollLeft(10000);
});
```

If you have timing issues with $(document).ready() firing too early and before the scroller has been initialized by the browser, give it a short delay:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".breadcrumb-scroller").scrollLeft(10000);
    }, 500);
});
```